# how to convert hhp from html in linux command line

Tags: html, command-line, ubuntu-14.04, chm

**My goal is to create .chm file from .fidl**, for that I used Doxygen.
Doxygen has several output formats. where html is the most basic. After creating html, I converted it to .chm (on windows) using HTML helper tool.

I would like to automate this process in ubuntu 14.04.
I am Able to convert .html from .fidl and after that I came to know we can create .chm from .hhp using chmcmd of free pascal.

But right now **I have .html file and my goal is to convert into .hhp file from html in linux via command line.**

This is why I am looking for the .chm from .html convertor in Linux. or .hhp convertor from .html.

Answer (score 1):

.hhp is a project file not a document format. It lists index and toc meta data that is generally not available in HTML (but can be sometimes harvested from H1/2/3/4/5 headers on a document specific basis) and general configuration of the CHM compiler. While it could be created automatically using heuristics, the quality will usually be low.

Moreover, then the positives of a standardized interface to the CHM compiler go away, and one might as well directly access the libraries behind the commandline frontend.

[This code](https://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk) is used to convert Freepascal documented generated by Tex4HT to chm.

Comment: Can we do the HTML to chm conversion in windows from command line.

Comment: Yes, whatever you program.

Comment: how we can program, do I need to instal any plugins or utilities to do so. I am not sure how I can program it from the command line. If you can direct that will be very helpfull.

Comment: No, the default fpc/lazarus install contains everything. chmcmd source itself is an example. fpdoc is a more complicated example.